# quicksort and selection sort method in python

Tags: python, list, class

```
class University:
        def __init__(self, name, numberoffaculity, numberofstudent):
            self.name = name
            self.numberoffaculity = numberoffaculity
            self.numberofstudent = numberofstudent


n = int(input())  # Number of universities that user wants to input
universities = []
for i in range(n):
    name = input()
    numberoffaculity = int(input())
    numberofstudent = int(input())
    uni = University(name, numberoffaculity, numberofstudent)
    universities.append(uni)

# Insert your code below this line


# Insert your code above this line

for uni in universities:
    print("%-10s %-10d %-10d"
          % (uni.name, uni.numberoffaculity, uni.numberofstudent))
```

My goal is: Program gets number **1** or **2**, and if it was 1, the list would be sorted and printed based on "**numberoffaculity**" from **large to small** by the **quicksort** method, and if it was **2**, the list would be sorted and printed based on "**numberofstudent**" from **small to large** by the **selection sort** method.

Comment: First you need to implement functions for quicksort and selection sort, and then you need to take the input and call the appropriate function.  Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: And you want to know how you can take an input and decide if it's 1 or 2? Or what is your question?

Comment: @Matthias, I am new in programming and I don't know How to write a sorting program.

Comment: If you don't know how to write a sorting function, you have two options: learn to write a sorting function (there are plenty of tutorials and examples out there, or you could even take a class that teaches Python programming), or use the built in `sort()` function instead of writing your own.  In real life, almost nobody writes their own sorting functions, because `sort()` already exists.

Comment: @Samwise, I need to write quicksort and "selection sort" function

Comment: Why can't you just use `universities.sort()`?

Comment: I am a statistics student and have just started programming in python. If I had to write this program in MATLAB, I would write it fast.

Comment: @Samwise, Because I do not know how to code in Python and this part of the program is part of a larger academic project.

Comment: If your goal is for you to write a sorting function yourself, then write it yourself (or at least make an effort that you can then get help with).  If your goal is for someone else to write a sorting function for you to use, **there is one already built into the language for you**, so just use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. First, I added quick_sort and selection_sort functions with a key function.

And then I called them based on the user input:

```
def quick_sort(array,key = lambda x:x):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    else:
        pivot = array[0]
        less = [i for i in array[1:] if key(i) <= key(pivot)]
        greater = [i for i in array[1:] if key(i) > key(pivot)]
        return quick_sort(less,key) + [pivot] + quick_sort(greater,key)


def selection_sort(lst,key = lambda x:x):
    empty_lst = []
    x = len(lst) - 1
    while x >= 0:
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            if key(lst[i]) <= key(lst[0]):
                lst[0], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[0]
                # this part compares the number in first index and numbers after the first index.
        g = lst.pop(0)
        empty_lst.append(g)
        x -= 1
    return empty_lst


user_input = int(input())
if user_input==1:
    universities = quick_sort(universities,key = lambda x:x.numberoffaculity)[::-1]
elif user_input==2:
    universities = selection_sort(universities,key = lambda x:x.numberofstudent)
else:
    print("invalid sort input , expected 1 or 2 and got %s"%user_input)
```

Comment: How do you expect people to learn if you're going to do their homework for them?